# get the whole content from the web site using perl script

Tags: perl

I am a new hire in my company and first time I am working on Perl.
   I get a task in which I find IP-Reputation from this link: https://www.talosintelligence.com/reputation_center/lookup?search=27.34.246.62

But in perl when we use:

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

open FILE1, ">./Reports/Reputation.txt" or die "Cannot open Reputation.txt!";
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );

my $url="https://www.talosintelligence.com/reputation_center/lookup?search=27.34.246.62";
$mech->get($url);
print $mech->status();
my $content = $mech->content();
open FILE1, ">./Reports/Reputation.txt" or die "Cannot open Reputation.txt!";
print FILE1 ($content);
close FILE1;
print "\nIP Reputation Report Generated \n";
```

I don't get the whole content. What can I do to get this?

Comment: Why do you `open FILE1` twice? Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Contents are loading from JavaScript. So you can't crawl the content using simple methods.

There is two option for this kind of situation.

1) Some API contains the original data and JavaScript loads/formating the data in front end. If you want to parse the JavaScript loading content try to use the
`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`

2) Try to figure out from where it is loading, for your IP following link has the corresponding data, which is JSON formated, so parse the content using JSON module. it is so simple compare to using RegEx.

https://www.talosintelligence.com/sb_api/query_lookup?query=%2Fapi%2Fv2%2Frelated_ips%2Fip%2F&query_entry=27.34.246.62

Comment: As doing following steps you will get the API links. Goto `Network`  by clicking the `Network` tap, then select the `XHR` option then reload the page, it will shows the API links.